# my website not worked in Ipad and how I can fix some small issue?

Tags: html, css, ipad

I have a website that's work fine in every browser. I have some issue in Ipad. I try many emulator but none of them worked.

Their is a problem that they have some small issue. Somebody can help me how I can solved them.

I have knowledge of  css to fix them but I don't have ipad. I have tried emulator and my designer also told me that they have checked it but emulator doesn't show me the problem that real ipad have.

now someone have any idea for getting it solved without have ipad. I means how I can fix it. Somebody please help me.  I just want to get something that show me the problem that user have seen on my site. This way after making changes I can verify it's solved or not.

Thanks

Comment: we use custom background over image that's not looking good in Ipad but fine in simulator. and another problem is custom looking search box have some issue in ipad. the image of button are not margin same as in search-textbox. If I tried any browser it's look great but failed in ipad as I seen in user's screenshot @AlanShortis

Comment: You can simulate the iPad using the web brower Safari. In developers mode Safari can use the user-agent for iPad to test. That might help you. Do you have any separate CSS for iPad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you ever heard about Responsive Web Design?
Twitter Bootstrap could be a good solution. Simply click on this link http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive

Another one you can use CSS Media Queries to detect device's screen. Also click
here to find out. http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: I am not sure what your means but our site is ready and we just want to fix 2 issue. please look at my comment I will post the image link for more detail

Comment: I can't guess what emulator you used, to me we already have device for testing and at least we used Google Chrome's Inspect Element tool to test the user agent. And all of my suggestions above can be used only if you are ready to start developing, but if you've already done, I don't think you could customize your project those ways.